# Adding A Hyperlink To An Individual Chart Series

Tags: excel, vba

I have selected the first series of my chart using the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
```

How do I add a hyperlink to only this series? I would like each chart series to have a different hyperlink, so would do the same for SeriesCollection(2) and on.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code in the Workbook:

```
Public WithEvents CHT As Chart
Const LinkVar = "http://www.google.com"

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set CHT = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart
End Sub

Private Sub CHT_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)
    On Error GoTo Fin
    If Selection.Name = "Series1" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=Sheet2.Range("A1").Value, _
        NewWindow:=True
    End If
    If Selection.Name = "Series2" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=LinkVar, _
        NewWindow:=True
    End If
Fin:

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If CHT Is Nothing Then
        Set CHT = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart
    End If
End Sub
```

you add an Select event connected to the chart.
Inside the event you check what you select and connect a Dynamic Hyperlink.
If you have more that one chart, it's necessary to check also the name of the Chart...

*(A little note: thanks also to me how ...)*
I have modify a little adding the reference to a cell in another sheet and add the address in a const.
I have also add the event SelectionChange, because sometimes when you modify the code the CHT var set on Nothing... In this event I check and eventually reSet.
Check to have in the cell referenced the correct syntax...

Comment: Thanks @user3514930, but I am afraid that I am slightly new to this and so would appreciate some more direction. I have copied the code through to a new class module, although when I select any of the series in the chart nothing happens. No link, no error - it's almost as if the code doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Comment: Add the Code in the WORKBOOK not in a CLASS MODULE. After you need to close and open, or run the sub Workbook_Open (from VBA manager). Otherwise don't work...

Comment: Thanks again @user3514930, the code now works to open up those webpages! To tie this into the data I am working with, would I simply replace the web address in the above code with "'Sheet2'!A1" to direct to the relevant worksheet? Or does this need a SubAddress? Moreover, can I replace the reference to Name with a dynamic reference (i.e. the series name is the contents of cell B4)?

Comment: Yes. You can modify in: Address:=Sheet2.Range("A1").Value or you can use a Name...

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to work, @user3514930. Inputting Address:=Sheet2.Range("A1").Value doesn't seem to link through to anything (although again, there is no error message). Neither does Address:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value